# "Latex" Surface Modifier interaction

Tags: modifiers

I'm looking to have interaction between object 1 (Suzanne) and object 2 (mesh / plane)
I've made try mixing "cast modifier" "clothes" "collision" 
How is it possible to see the Suzanne in the mesh when Suzanne is closed to it ?
The picture is the cast modifiers

Best

Zoltan
[image: Cast Modifiers]

Comment: any suggestions will be really appreciate